# Is it possible to save template object in JSON file with JSON standard format?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, dynamic

I have a vue project, where I dynamically load the template from a JS variable. I do it like this:

```js
<template>
<component v-else :is="templateObject"></component>
</template>
<script>
import templateObject from './templateObject.vue';

export default {
  name: 'vueProject',
  data() {
    return {
      html:{
      template: templateObject
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to be able to save the html variable in a JSON file (model.json) and load it later. I can only write this in model.json

`{ "template": "vueTemplate"}`

But it wont work because template is interpreted as a string. Any ideas how do I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your `is` reference. The way you have your `data` written in your example snippet, the `component` should look like this:

```
<template>
<!-- some other element with v-if -->
<component v-else :is="html.template"></component>
</template>
```

As for storing template references in JSON, it seems you have the following options:

1. Store the file path reference, use a dynamic import to fetch the component object, and use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State)
2. Store the html template string in the value (e.g. `{ "template": "<div>my component</div>"`) - This seems like a maintenance nightmare... I don't recommend this option

Comment: This sounds like a smart solution! I will try this next Monday and give the results.